# Access Forbidden! Apache Windows XP

Tags: htaccess, xampp, 403-forbidden

[This is a great tutorial](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/11/making-xampp-to-serve-any-directory-outside-htdocs/) on how to server websites other than in default htdocs folder in XAMPP. It worked for me the other day but then I had to reinstall XAMPP (1.7.7 was 1.7.6) and now I am getting this error when I try the same.

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
```

I have put this in *http.conf* file according to the above link

```
<Directory "C:/Blog">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /blog/ "C:/Blog" # this goes inside the alias module
```

When I type the URL, I get these messages:

```
localhost/blog       #gets error, object not found
localhost/blog/      #Access Foribdden
localhost/blog2/     #this folder does not exist and it rightly says object not found
```

Note that I have added ***everyone*** user to blog folder but still have the problem. I have added a plain HTML file as well but still have the same problem. I cannot find a *.htaccess* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it got fixed, but I played with this line

```
Alias /blog/ "C:/Blog"
```

changed it to `C:/Blog/` which did not work, and then changed it back to what it is above and it starting working. It took at least half an hour of my time.

### More

I began the same error (Access forbidden) again after I changed the port to 8080. This time the fix was changing the above line to

```
Alias /blog/ "C:/Blog/"
```

This is very unclear how this one line can create such error.